# Complete incompletely linked documents (document trees) with a lookup-list using a function

Tags: r, purrr, lookup-tables

I have linked documents (document trees) saved in a list (`list`)

Some of the documents trees have items that are not complete (marked with `seach=1`). Some trees might have multiple incomplete trees that are marked with `search=1`.

I would like to extend/complete these incomplete trees using lookup list that contain document trees (`list_lookup`), there is always only one matching tree in list and `list_lookup`. The `level` of the matching document tree should be adjusted to the document tree in `list`.

Sample data and desired output:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# initial df1, aaa is incomplete (it is in fact linked to other documents, but this information is stored in the lookup list)
 
df1 <- tibble(id_from=c(NA_character_,"111","222","333","444","444","bbb"),
             id_to=c("111","222","333","444","aaa","bbb","ccc"),
             level=c(0,1,2,3,4,4,5),
             search=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
df1
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   id_from id_to level search
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 <NA>    111       0      0
#> 2 111     222       1      0
#> 3 222     333       2      0
#> 4 333     444       3      0
#> 5 444     aaa       4      1
#> 6 444     bbb       4      0
#> 7 bbb     ccc       5      0


# lookup dfs, df2 contains the further document links of aaa
df2 <- tibble(id_from=c(NA,"aaa","x","x"),
             id_to=c("aaa","x","x1","x2"),
             level=c(0,1,2,2))

df3 <- tibble(id_from=c(NA,"thank"),
                     id_to=c("thank","you"),
                     level=c(0,1))

#list with df
list <- list(df1)

#list with lookups
list_lookup <- list(df2,df3)

list_lookup
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   id_from id_to level
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 <NA>    aaa       0
#> 2 aaa     x         1
#> 3 x       x1        2
#> 4 x       x2        2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   id_from id_to level
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 <NA>    thank     0
#> 2 thank   you       1

#what I need; an updated list of dfs where information from the lookup list are included

df1_wanted <- tibble(id_from=c(NA_character_,"111","222","333","444","444","aaa","bbb","x","x"),
                     id_to=c("111","222","333","444","aaa","bbb","x","ccc","x1","x1"),
                     level=c(0,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6))

list(df1_wanted)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    id_from id_to level
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 <NA>    111       0
#>  2 111     222       1
#>  3 222     333       2
#>  4 333     444       3
#>  5 444     aaa       4
#>  6 444     bbb       4
#>  7 aaa     x         5  <- added from df2, level adjusted
#>  8 bbb     ccc       5  
#>  9 x       x1        6  <- added from df2, level adjusted
#> 10 x       x1        6  <- added from df2, level adjusted
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My approach:

I thought about using `purrr::map` to map a function to every item of `list`, however, I am not sure how this function should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this solution:

1. I first define a recursive function, `get_tree()`, that takes a single `id` and lookup table and returns the full tree from the table for that `id`.
2. Then, I define a function, `complete_tree()`, that takes a dataframe and a list of lookup tables, iterates over `get_tree()` for every `id_to` where `search == 1` and for each lookup table, adjusts `level`, and binds the results to the initial dataframe.
3. Finally, I iterate over `complete_tree()` for every element of `list`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

get_tree <- function(id, lookup) {
  branch <- filter(lookup, id_from == id)
  if (nrow(branch) == 0) return()
  bind_rows(
    branch, 
    map(branch$id_to, \(x) get_tree(x, lookup))
  )
}

complete_trees <- function(data, lookups) {
  branches <- pmap(
    filter(data, search == 1),
    \(id_to, level, ...) {
      bind_rows(map(
          lookups, 
          \(lookup) get_tree(id_to, lookup)
        )) %>%
        mutate(level = level + .env$level)
    }
  )
  bind_rows(data, branches) %>%
    select(!search) %>%
    arrange(level, id_from)
}

map(list, \(x) complete_trees(x, lookups = list_lookup))
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   id_from id_to level
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
 1 <NA>    111       0
 2 111     222       1
 3 222     333       2
 4 333     444       3
 5 444     aaa       4
 6 444     bbb       4
 7 aaa     x         5
 8 bbb     ccc       5
 9 x       x1        6
10 x       x2        6
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a marvellous solution. I now tried to cut branches with a similar approach but I got stuck again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910943/cut-branches-of-linked-documents-document-trees-with-a-lookup-list-using-a-fun. Do you maybe have another hint?